# SEO really important? Are there any studies?

Tags: seo

I'm studying at a university, and it's really important to be able to support arguments with facts. Are there any studies about SEO? I've read that people don't bother to go to the next page on google, they do a new search instead. But are there really any studies in the subject?

Comment: While we all know that lots of people will choose a link from the top of the list, I would guess that most of the "studies" will have been published by SEO providers so the figures may be skewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But are there really any studies in the subject?

For example, the [pie chart on this page](http://training.seobook.com/google-ranking-value) says that 40% of clicks are on the top (number 1) search result, that 90% are on the first page, and that 0.01% are on neither pages 1 and 2.